# Python Tkinter Entry.focus() doesn't work

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I have problem with Tkinter on `macOS` system with many things, and one of them is the method `.focus()` doesn't work, despite I do according to a guide from `Udemy` and the author has `macOS` to.

So I tried to put in the focus `Entry` from `Tkinter`. I've done it in two ways, because there people how tall is the `.focus()` has to be before .grid(), but in video `.focus()` was after `.grid()`. In both cases, it doesn't work.

Has someone have this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a larger code sample, please? (pastebin perhaps, if it's a lot of code)

Comment: did u apply any focus on elements ? Because I just tested and it works.

Comment: @H.Syd: we don't want a pastbin. The code should be able to fit easily into the question itself.

Comment: Please provide a small but complete [mcve]. Your code as posted seems to work when we supply what we are guessing is the missing code. Also, please don't post code as a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `website_input.focus()` or `website_input.focus_set()`. Once u already had problem with `.focus()`, can you try `focus_set()`. I have tested both function in below code and both are worked well.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("750x250")

entry= Entry(root, width= 25)
entry.focus()

entry.pack()

#or entry.focus_set()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: focus_set is an alias for focus. Therefore it should not make a difference.

Comment: Expanding on the comment above: in the [`tkinter` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0821923aa979a72464c5da8dfa53a719bba5801c/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L788) , they use `focus = focus_set` so `focus` and `focus_set` refer to the same method.

Comment: Hi 
sorry, I  should'd sent you a whole code. So today I deleted I row import tkmacosx and it helped. Beside tkmacosx didn't help me with tkinter buttons at all, they are still ugly.  
And yes, both function .focus() and .focus_set() work, so thank you.

Comment: if want create modern tkinter, try to use customtkinter. It's much better than tkinter and others

Comment: @MuhammedSamedÖzmen
Thank you I've would try. Because regular Tkinter doesn't work properly on MacOS and it's annoying.
And thanks for your help. It was really fast compare to the author of course I'm doing.

Comment: @H.Syd 
I think you have a point, but since we talking about tkinter in MacOs I thing we can expect everything :) But thank you for this TIP

Comment: @TheLizzard
I think you have a point, but since we talking about tkinter in MacOs I thing we can expect everything :) But thank you for this TIP